# Map varchar to nvarchar for the whole app

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a Grails application which uses MSSQL as database-server. Now the application should be  deployed in Russia.

How can I make GORM map strings to nvarchar instead of varchar for the whole application as I don't want to use sqlType in mapping for each string field. Does anybody know where I can modify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `grails.gorm.default.mapping` for this, and you can find documentation [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Database%20Mapping/Usage.html) and [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#ormdsl)